# How to force user to change password?

Tags: users

I am using Force password change module to give a facility to user to reset the password after their first login. So far, I have installed the module and after creating the user, when I click on edit link, I could see the *force user to change password* check box option. But I am unable to see the same option in add user page (while creating user).

Any suggestions about how to enable same option on add user page?

[image]

Comment: You can change passwords for users who exists on your system, what  you mean by adding the same option on user add page as well?

Comment: @arpitr: please do check the screen shot which i have added , and the force user to change password option check box is showing only in user edit page but i want this option while creating the user which means add user page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can navigate to this url `admin/config/people/force_password_change`
and check `Force password change on first-time login` option or you can configure based on roles too.

In that case you will get a option in both create and edit user as shown in screenshort.[image]